# Preventing session timeout during long processing time in JSF

Tags: jsf, session-timeout

I've been working on an JSF application. At one place, I've to call an action in managed bean. The action actually process hundreds of records and the session timesout before the processing is finished.

Though all the records are processed successfully, the session expires and the user is sent to login page.

I'd tried adding

session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);

before the processing of the records with no effect.

How to prevent the session time out during such process.

Comment: have you configured session timeout in web.xml to appropriate value

Comment: yes i did. but my client required less session timout period for rest of others. currently its 3 mins.

Comment: try using session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1), setting value 0 actually invalidates the session.

Comment: @Nayan Wadekar - I tried using session.setMaxInactiveIntercal(-1). Since in javadoc its mention as
"An interval value of zero or less indicates that the session should never timeout." 
So, I tried using zero.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Introduce ajaxical polls to keep the session alive as long as enduser has the page open in webbrowser. Here's a kickoff example with a little help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get('poll');
        }, ${(pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval - 10) * 1000});
    });
</script>
```

Here [`${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval%28%29) returns the remnant of seconds the session has yet to live (and is been deducted with 10 seconds -just to be on time with poll- and converted to milliseconds so that it suits what [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) expects).

The [`$.get('poll')`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) should call a servlet which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/poll` and contains basically the following line in the `doGet()` method.

```
request.getSession(); // Keep session alive.
```

That's it.

Comment: This would eventually disturb the sites functionality as the questioner requires 3mins session timeout.

Comment: @niksvp: feel free to post a better solution.

Comment: @BalusC - I would like to add to your answer, to wrap the script in any JSF component and render that part only when action is called, ideally it should not be rendered.

Comment: @BalusC - I doubt if this works because I tried to keep the session alive by introducing a4j:poll. Once the form is submitted, aj4:poll stops sending request to the server.

Comment: Either just submit the form by ajax as well, or redo the poll in the result page of the form submit.

Comment: I'll try once sending ajax request to make a4j:poll to work. Thanks BalusC

Comment: Hi BalusC. Do you have any idea how to use a heartbeat with SEAM and Richfaces? See my question on http://stackoverflow.com/q/14647608/42659.

Comment: why am I getting Expected , but found {
    },  ${(pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval - 10) * 1000});

Expected ; but found )
    },  ${(pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval - 10) * 1000});
----
error in netbeans?

Comment: @kinkajou: Ignore'n'run it. If it works, then it's just Netbeans itself being wrong -again.

Comment: @BalusC I have the code saved in .js file. It complains ) is missing ! It works if I put a number. `$(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get('poll');
        }, 5000);
    });` . Also poll works only if it is deployed on root I think. Some **project name/poll**

Comment: @kinkajou: EL expressions are by default not evaluated in a .js file.

Comment: @BalucC So, I send it as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent session timeout, try using thread to do processing.

By doing this way, user will be able to do other activities & don't hang up waiting for the process to complete.

Comment: since the process is financial transaction related, it must be synchronous and client need to wait for the process to finish.

Comment: wadekar - I'm afraid to introduce thread as it may bring unpleasant surprises in web applications. Thanks.

Comment: yes may be, but threads are inevitable part of any application & it depends on how we manage them.