# How do I set session timeout in seconds in web.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a requirement to set the session timeout of 40 seconds. I know we keep normally to 20 minutes.

But my current application requirement is to keep the session timeout to 40 seconds. The web.xml is taking only integer value as 1 but it is not taking 0.6. Is there any way to write this? We are running our java web application on Apache tomcat server.

So how do I set session timeout in seconds in web.xml?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382895/session-timeout-in-web-xml

for more information

Answer (score 14):

Using the [*deployment descriptor*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbj/index.html), you can only set the timeout **in minutes**:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

But using the [HttpSession](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval-int-) API you can set the session timeout **in seconds** for a *servlet container*:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(40);
```

---

Suggested reading: [Deployment Descriptor Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017275)

Comment: this will treat as 40 mins not secs.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari Fixed.

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html states that setMaxInactiveInterval is for specifying the time in seconds

Answer (score 3):

well in web.xml file you can provide in minutes

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>Minutes</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

but you programatically provide values in seconds

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20*60);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Timeout in the deployment descriptor (web.xml)
```

– Specified the timeout value in “minute” , enclose with “session-config” element.

Markup

```
<web-app ...>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

The above setting is apply for the entire web application, and session will be kill by container if client doesn’t make any request after 20 minutes.

```
2) Timeout with setMaxInactiveInterval()
```

– You can manually specified the timeout value in “second” for a particular session.

Java

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20*60);
```

The above setting is only apply on session which call the “setMaxInactiveInterval()” method, and session will be kill by container if client doesn’t make any request after 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the session timeout through "setMaxInactiveInterval()".

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20000);
```

here it will take the time in milliseconds, means in next 20 seconds session will get expire.

Comment: setMaxInactiveInterval takes value in seconds

Answer (score 0):

How do i set session timeout in seconds in web.xml?
Solution: Try this
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET) // Your token here
res.cookie('Cookie', token, { expire: new Date(Date.now()+ 9999)})