# Vaadin 8 set session timeout

Tags: java, session, vaadin, vaadin8

How to set timeout of a session in Vaadin 8?

I am not using web.xml, which has been the place to set it in prior versions of the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

You can set the standard Servlet session’s timeout as a `int` number of whole seconds, after extracting from the wrapping `VaadinSession`.

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval ( ( int ) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( 30 ) ) ;
```

## Set session timeout programmatically

Setting the [session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)) timeout is a feature in your [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container), your Servlet engine, such as Tomcat, Jetty, etc. The [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) spec defines this behavior for Java apps as part of its session handling.

Vaadin wraps the Servlet session inside a [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.1/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html). So extract the regular Servlet session from Vaadin as a [`WrappedSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.1/com/vaadin/server/WrappedSession.html), then call the [`setMaxInactiveInterval`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.1/com/vaadin/server/WrappedSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval-int-) method to set the time to expire.

Specify the time limit as a number of whole seconds. The `TimeUnit` enum is handy to calculate the seconds without resorting to [“magic” numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

```
VaadinSession               // Wraps a standard Servlet session.
.getCurrent()               // Access the current user’s session.
.getSession()               // Access the wrapped standard Servlet session.
.setMaxInactiveInterval(    // Set the timeout.
    ( int )                 // Cast a `long` to an `int`.
    TimeUnit                // The `TimeUnit` enum is more self-documenting than using a literal integer number.
    .MINUTES                // Here we set a half hour, 30 minutes.
    .toSeconds( 30 )        // Set a number of whole seconds.      
)
;
```

Here is a complete example Vaadin 8.5 app created from the Maven archetype `vaadin-archetype-application`. We added a single line to the beginning of the `init` method.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent a browser window
 * (or tab) or some part of an HTML page where a Vaadin application is embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This method is intended to be
 * overridden to add component to the user interface and initialize non-component functionality.
 */
@Theme ( "mytheme" )
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest vaadinRequest ) {
        // Set Session timeout programmatically. Overrides the default timeout configured for Servlet.
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval( ( int ) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( 45 ) );  // Setting timeout of 45 minutes = ( 45 * 60 ) seconds.

        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        final TextField name = new TextField();
        name.setCaption( "Type your name here:" );

        Button button = new Button( "Click Me" );
        button.addClickListener( e -> {
            layout.addComponent( new Label( "Thanks " + name.getValue()
                                                + ", it works!" ) );
        } );

        layout.addComponents( name , button );

        setContent( layout );
    }

    @WebServlet ( urlPatterns = "/*",
        name = "MyUIServlet",
        asyncSupported = true )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( ui = MyUI.class,
        productionMode = false )
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

## Servlet, not Vaadin

> I am not using web.xml, which has been the place to set it in prior versions of the framework.

Actually, the session timeout is a Servlet thing, not a Vaadin-specific thing. And the `web.xml` is a Servlet thing, not a Vaadin-specific thing.

See:

- [`javax.servlet.http.HttpSession::setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval-int-) method
- [Servlet 3.1 specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-3.1/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf) (a PDF document)
- [Servlet 4 specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=369)

Further discussed in [*How to set session timeout dynamically in Java web applications?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2960764/642706).

Comment: Thanks. I think 30 is still a magic number in your example, better use a constant SESSION_TIMEOUT_HALF_HOUR or anything like it. But nevertheless thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Session timeout is set in web.xml.

If you don't have one, then you will need to create one.

[How do i set session timeout in seconds in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005600/how-do-i-set-session-timeout-in-seconds-in-web-xml)

As you seem to use spring boot, then this might apply to you

[Spring Boot Java Config Set Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974955/spring-boot-java-config-set-session-timeout)

Comment: Where should this file be located? I am using spring boot

Comment: @StimpsonCat Alternatively, you can programmatically set it by calling `VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(numberOfSeconds);` in your `init` method for example.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18821037)

Comment: @grizzthedj Agree for external links, but these are also stackoverflow posts. If the user had a more clear question, I could have marked it as duplicate of the spring boot stuff.

Comment: The question is clear all the time. But the comments did not help, because they do not work