# Heartbeat while having a long-lasting request

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, session-timeout, seam2

How can I implement a heartbeat with JSF 1.2, RichFaces 3.x using SEAM 2.x which also works during a long-lasting request executed by an user?

Currently, we've got a heartbeat (to avoid session timeout) using `<aj4:poll action="#{bean.keepAlive}" ... />` which does not work during long-lasting requests on the server. Using an own `eventsQueue="heartbeat"` allows that the required heartbeat is sent even while executing a long-term request *but* leads us into a `org.jboss.seam.ConcurrentRequestTimeoutException`.

We also tried using `@Asynchronous`on the `keepAlive` method.

Do you have another solution or a hint to my problem? Thank you. :)

---

- http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.1.GA/reference/en/html/conversations.html#d0e5208

Comment: Would it work if you moved the keepAlive to an separate and standalone bean? That way, it *may* be exempt from the Concurrency issue.

Comment: No it's not working. The concurrency issue is raised by SEAM. Maybe I do have to try another `ScopeType`?

Comment: I am not sure if it is that simple. A cleaner solution *might* be to get the long running process to run in the background (Asynchronously). You can then check for the completion state and the results on a regular basis until the background task completes. I think the problem you are having is that every request from that page is being tied to the same context. If you can somehow request without hitting the same context, it *might* work!

Comment: Thank you. I've followed your suggestions but since the long-running request must have access to the current context, using `Asynchronous` or a thread did not work.

Comment: However, we've found a solution which works for us. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved our problem running the heartbeat within a `<iframe ...>`. I'm actually not a friend of using frames but in this situation it's a clean quick and dirty solution.

We're still using `<a4j:poll ...>` within the frame.