# How to refresh the page at a specific interval

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to refresh the page one minute before the session is expired.

```
#{seesion.maxInactiveInterval – 60}
```

It looks like p:poll is the suitable API for this but how can I set the interval ?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/poll.jsf

```
 <p:poll interval="#{session.maxInactiveInterval - 60}"  update="txt_count" />
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4526382/617373 by BalusC

Answer (score 0):

@Angus

I believe you want to refresh the page before your session expires.
Means your session gets expired if user activity is idle for more than 60 seconds.

So yes you can use primefaces `p:poll` `component` as

```
<p:poll interval="59" update="txt_count" />
```

At property `interval` we can define time in seconds, after this specified time interval our page will get refreshed.

Hope this helps